# R - separate with specific symbol, vertical bare, |

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, separator

I have a dataset with a column with the symbol '|' (come from the interaction of 2 variables in a model), and I want to split it according this character.

The function separate works well with standard character, **do you how I can specific the character '|' ?**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Interaction = c('var1|var2'))

# as expected
df %>% separate(Interaction, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '1')
#   var1  var2
# 1  var |var2

# not as expected
df %>% separate(Interaction, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '|')
#   var1 var2
# 1         v
```

Comment: u csn escape it  `
|

Comment: I didn't know what "escape something" means, it is more clear with your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can either escape (`\\`) the `|` as it is a metacharacter for regex specifying for `OR` and the `sep` by default is in the `regex` mode

If we look at the `?separate` documentation,

> separate(data, col, into, sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove = TRUE,
>     convert = FALSE, extra = "warn", fill = "warn", ...)

and it is described as

> sep - If character, is interpreted as a regular expression. The default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.

```
df %>% 
  separate(Interaction, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '\\|')
```

or place it in square brackets

```
df %>% 
   separate(Interaction, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '[|]')
```

Comment: always the most beautiful solutions

Answer (score 0):

Vertical bar is a special character, that's why is not performing as expected:

```
df %>% separate(Interaction, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '\\|')
```

That should solve the problem.